# using bitbucket in windows, but cant get tortoisehg

Tags: windows, tortoisehg, bitbucket

trying to use bitbucket in windows. but mercurial wont install in windows, and tortoisehg cant download because cdn.bitbucket.com didnt connect(here in China, but I break the GFW and facebook etc. is available)

So, is the windows version of mercurial tortoisehg? If so, why I got a mercurial-2.5.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe? Any other solutions to clone from bitbucket?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to use one of the [Mercurial installers for Windows](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download)?

Comment: the mercurial installer installed all of its components under the python27 folder. I cant find the command line client

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseHG is just a graphical shell for Mercurial. You can get by using just the command line client.

After installing the package in `mercurial-2.5.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`, try typing `hg --help` at a command prompt.

Comment: the mercurial installer installed all of its components under the python27 folder. I cant find the command line client